# How to expand the projection in SELECT if a condition is met?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I need to select (do a projection) only basic set of columns from the query result. Therefore I have an expression defined, listing all of the required properties:

```
Expression<Func<Input, Output>> basicExpression = x => new Output 
{
  OutputProp1 = x.TABLE1.TABLE2.InputProp1
}
```

I can use this variable in a `Select` statement:

```
dbContext.Input.Select(basicExpression)
```

If a specific flag in the system is set to true, I should project one more field called **OutputProp2**

Is there a way of how could I *inject* the Member init expression into the original `Select` expression?

```
Expression<Func<Input, Output>> basicExpression = x => new Output 
{
  OutputProp1 = x.TABLE1.TABLE2.InputProp1,
  OutputProp2  <------ insert this prop here if a flag is set to true
}
```

I cannot simply replace the reference to `basicExpression` because the query will vary depending on a combination of flags enabled/disabled in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output.OutputProp exists whether your condition is True or False so it doesn't make sense to "add" it to the expression or not based on a condition, rather set it based on the condition:

```
Expression<Func<Input, Output>> basicExpression = x => new Output 
{
  OutputProp1 = x.TABLE1.TABLE2.InputProp1,
  OutputProp2 = flag ? x.TABLE1.TABLE2.SomeProp/Calc : default;
}
```

Now whether you can ensure EF can still translate the entire expression down to SQL is another can of worms. :)